# Clearing the submitted state of a form in Angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is it possible to manually set the submitted state to true/false in Angular 6? I can markAsPristine and form.reset(), but these don't have an affect on the submitted state...

The form lives in a modal and continues to exist in the DOM after submitting. This leads to myForm.submitted being true and triggers CSS error classes when the modal opens again.

Thank in advance!

SOLUTION:
as statated by @igor resetForm() is what i wanted, however i was using it wrongly.

```
  myForm.form.controls['description'].reset(); // works perfectly fine
  myForm.form.resetForm(); // is not a function
  myForm.resetForm(); // works perfectly fine
```

Comment: @igor myForm.submitted

Comment: What do you mean by submitted state? Do you want to submit the form programmatically.?

Comment: @BearNithi the form lives in a modal and continues to exist after submitting, this leads to submitted being true and triggering CSS error classes when the modal opens again as the form was technically already submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`NgForm.resetForm`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#resetform)

Documentation:

> ### resetForm()
>
> Resets the form to an initial value and resets its submitted status.

Comment: See, I do that and it clears the form, but submitted remains set to true - truly bizarre

Comment: @Dbrandt - Based on the documentation it should work. Could you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)?

Comment: I use reset() and it clears the form, however using resetForm() shows "myForm.form.resetForm is not a function" - I will create a stackblitz shortly

Comment: @Dbrandt awesome, glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

Angular's NgForm.resetForm() function claims to reset the submitted state: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#resetform

To quote the docs:

> resetForm() - Resets the form to an initial value and resets its submitted status.
>
> resetForm(value: any = undefined): void
>
> value - any - The new value for the form. Optional. Default is undefined.
>
> returns void

Answer (score 1):

**If `NgForm.resetForm` is not what you were looking for then read below**

FormGroup itself doesn't have an option to manually set submitted property.

However what you can do is get a reference to directive and set submitted on that

In your template

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" #myFormDirective></form>
```

and in your typescript

```
@ViewChild('myFormDirective',  {read: FormGroupDirective}) myFormDirective: FormGroupDirective;


setSubmit(state) {
  (this.myFormDirectiveas any).submitted = state;
}
```